# Assessing a distribution from multiple estimates of its mean

Tags: estimation, derived-distributions

I face a random variable whose distribution I don't know.

Someone draws a sample of **k** observations from a population and tells me their average. He repeats the process **m** times.

I assume m is in order of magnitude of hundreds.

If 1 < k < 20, What can I tell about the population variance?

What about other lower moments?

If k=1, I can trivially draw the emplirical distribution. What is the closest analoug for 1 < k < 20?

Comment: What do you mean by "approximating the original population"?

Comment: @Tim, I mean to have the best fit I can of the original distribution. Having a good approximation of its lower moments would be a nice start. Another direction would be an analoug of the empirical distribution (with k=1 it is trivial, what if k=2 or k=3 ?)

Comment: Could you edit to make it more precise (e.g. by defining what "small" k means, by defining what do you want to learn about the distribution etc.)?

Comment: Even for the case $k=1$ this is a broad question: it covers the entire theory of estimation.  Could you focus it by giving more information about any assumptions that can be made about the unknown distribution?

Comment: @whuber and Tim, thank you for your focusing comments.
I rephrased my question.